# Laravel Static Create methods to insert record return null id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-6

I'm working with Laravel 7 and tinker cli

I want to insert a record in Profile table with static create method but it returns null value of id column not value provided by me but automatically incremented in database.
In following image i had make an array -> then pass it to create method -> record inserted but ***id column is not accessible***

[image: Insertion done using tinker cli]

**I had changed default primary key 'id' of laravel 7 to username**  , without changing primary key create() method returns  correct value , Please tell me how it will give value of id in my case using username as a primary key

[image: Record inserted with id value but returns null how access it]

**Record inserted with id value but returns null how access it after inserting using create() method**

Profile Migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateProfilesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('profiles');
    }
}
```

Profile Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profile extends Model
{
    protected $guarded =[];

    protected $primaryKey='username';
    protected  $keyType='string';
    public $incrementing=false;
}
```

Comment: replace `$table->id();` by `$table->integer('id');`

Comment: Not solves problem